# Android: Emulator won't open menu in app

Tags: android, android-activity, menu

I'm having a rather odd issue where the menu for an activity works totally fine on real device but not on the emulator.

I tried launching one of my older projects in the emulator that I remember the menus working in, and it also failed.  I suppose some sort of update has caused this?

The code is simple...

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem prefs = menu.add("Preferences");
    prefs.setIcon(R.drawable.gear_01);
    return true;
}
```

LogCat displays series of exceptions ultimately caused by:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(6714): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-hdpi/ic_menu_more.png
```

This actually happens not only in my applications but on the home screen to.

Any ideas for solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to find error in your code.
So try this.Create one Folder in res named menu.Put this xml inside this folder

**Make Sure you have icon in your drawable names ic_new_game,ic_help**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/new_game"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
      android:title="@string/new_game"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item android:id="@+id/help"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
      android:title="@string/help" />
</menu>
```

Override this method as you did

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
return true;
}
```

Comment: Wait... what are these icons ice_new_game and ic_help...
Are they system files?  They aren't in my actual folder.  Why is this all of a sudden necessary?  And what should this XML be called?

Comment: This is image store in your drawable folder.You can remove it.Then it will show only title.Its necessary to create a menu.XMl has two menu component that will show in menu.If you like then please consider it to accept of upvote

Comment: you can create menu dynamically.But using xml is easy comparatively.In above link they have mention how to create menu dynamically also

Comment: Ah so just create a menu with all the items in XML... ok got it.